# Adding a if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My code looks like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?utm_source=' + utm_source  + '&utm_campaign' + utm_campaign + '&utm_medium' + utm_medium);
});
```

The code adds some UTM Parameters to all Links on a site. But now I want to exclude some specific links:

```
https://www.mysite.or/cat1
https://www.mysite.or/cat2
```

So I came up with that:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  if ("href:contains('https://www.mysite.or/cat1')") {
    $(this).attr('href');
  } else if ("href:contains('https://www.mysite.or/cat1')") {
    $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_campaign' + utm_campaign + '&utm_medium' + utm_medium);
  }
});
```

But it isn't working properly.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href');` returns the value of the attribute, so you're missing a left side assignment

Comment: Maybe change the if to only go further when the statement is not true? 
Like `if (href != 'https://www.mysite-com/cat' && href != "other site name")`
If you have a lot of if statments change it to be a switch case instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better if you create a list of excluded domains so it will be easier to add more in the future. For example like this:

```
var exclude = [
  "https://www.mysite.or/cat1",
  "https://www.anysite.com"
]

$('a').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (exclude.indexOf(href) === -1) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_campaign' + utm_campaign + '&utm_medium' + utm_medium);
  }
});
```

---

As @caramba pointed out in the comments, the above solution is not the fastest if you care about performance (i.e you have thousands of `a` to iterate over, or tens of excluded domains). Another possible solution (while keeping the code easy to maintain) is to build a selector and pass it to jQuery:

```
var exclude = [
  "https://www.mysite.or/cat1",
  "https://www.anysite.com"
]

var nots = exclude.map(function(domain) {
    return ':not([href="' + domain + '"])';
}).join('');

$('a' + nots).each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_campaign' + utm_campaign + '&utm_medium' + utm_medium);
});
```

Comment: I cant use the const because This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better. Is there a alternative to const?

Comment: It's supported by almost every browser now: https://caniuse.com/#search=const. But if you still want to change it, you can replace `const` with `var`. Edited the answer

Comment: Do the [] declare a const - cause i got the error again

Comment: Sorry to say, but seems important to note: In terms of performance this is the worst answer. `1` all a tags are selected which could be many including many not related ones. `2` a loop over all those a tags is needed. `3` inside the loop another loop over all "excluded" elements is needed which could all have been avoided at the `1st` step

Comment: Considering that the amount of excluded domains will be at most a couple this is really a fight for a few milliseconds while losing readability. The performance difference will become important if a number of usages of excluded domains will be significant compared to the amount of `a`s. Otherwise, you want to iterate over almost all `a` tags anyway and iterate at most a couple of times over `excluded` array which increases readability compared to building a huge selector.

Comment: But for the sake of completeness and because my answer is accepted so will be viewed most times, I'll edit my post according to your suggestions if you let me. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Exclude all the url not required by reducing the scope of the selector

```
$('a:not([href$="cat1"]):not([href$="cat2"])').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', ...);
});
```

`$=` means *attribute ending with*

```js
 $('a:not([href$="cat1"]):not([href$="cat2"])').each(function() {
     $(this).html('changed')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="http://somelink/cat0">untouched</a>
<a href="http://somelink/cat1">untouched</a>
<a href="http://somelink/cat2">untouched</a>
<a href="http://somelink/cat3">untouched</a>
<a href="http://somelink/cat4">untouched</a>
```

Comment: Thank you - but it isnt working. Now no Link is working.

Comment: @Tomtom my bad, a typo on the selector. see the update

Answer (score 1):

you could also do something like:

```
$('a:not([href^="https://www.mysite.or/cat"])')
```

which will only select `<a>` tags not containing a href which starts with `https://www.mysite.or/cat`

```js
$('a:not([href^="https://www.mysite.or/cat"])').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('found');
});
```

```css
.found {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">some</a>
<a href="https://www.mysite.or/cat2">xxx1</a>
<a href="https://www.mysite.or/cat1">xxx1</a>
```